# Формула max (x, y+sqrt(x))

Tags: c++

Есть формула: max (x, y+sqrt(x)), как записать ее на С++?

Пробовал так, но Borland ругается:

```
std::max(x,y+sqrt(x))
```

Вот само условие:

[image: Вот само условие]

Comment: "Borland ругается" - напишите, как точно он ругается.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
//...
const double F = (x > 0.0 && y >= 0.0) 
                          ? 
                            std::max(x,y + sqrt(x) )
                          : 
                 (x < 0.0)    
                          ? 
                            std::min(pow(sin(x),2.0),cos(pow(y,2.0)))
                          :
                            0.5 * x + exp(y);
```

Comment: Во-первых, там `cos` от `y` в квадрате, а во-вторых, возводить в квадрат с помощью `pow`?...

Answer (score 2):

Ну напишите свои функции, это же несложно!

```
inline double min(double x, double y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }
inline double max(double x, double y) { return (x > y) ? x : y; }

double F(double x, double y)
{
    if (x > 0.0 && y >= 0.0) return max(x,sqrt(y));
    else if (x < 0) { double s = sin(x); return min(s*s, cos(y*y)); }
    else return 0.5*x + exp(y);
}
```

Comment: Прокомментирую в вашем же стиле: "писать самопальные минимум и максимум?"

Comment: @gbg :) Не имея Borland, не могу быть уверенным, что проблема не просто в том, что версия какая-то старая, в которой этой функциональности просто нет. А поскольку вопроситель :) уже в отчаянии - предложил workaround - после того, как ему пару раз советовали std::max и min...